# awk split carrying-over whitespace

Tags: awk

The below `awk` split appears to be leaving the whitespace in after `$4~ in the output and I can not seem to prevent it.  What is the correct syntax?  Thank you :).

**input**

```
chr1    955543  955763  + AGRN-6|pr=2|gc=75
chr1    957571  957852  + AGRN-7|pr=3|gc=61.2
chr1    970621  970740  + AGRN-8|pr=1|gc=57.1
```

**Current output**

```
chr1    955543  955763  +   AGRN-6|gc=75
chr1    957571  957852  +   AGRN-7|gc=61.2
chr1    970621  970740  +   AGRN-8|gc=57.1

gawk '{print gensub(/(^[^|]+)\|[^|]+([|][^+]+).*/,"\\1\\2","g",$0)}' input
```

**edit**

```
chr1^I955543^I955763^I+ AGRN-6|gc=75$
chr1^I957571^I957852^I+ AGRN-7|gc=61.2$
chr1^I970621^I970740^I+ AGRN-8|gc=57.1$
```

**desired**

```
chr1^I955542^I955662^I+^IAGRN_70$
chr1^I955643^I955763^I+^IAGRN_71$
chr1^I957570^I957690^I+^IAGRN_72$
```

Comment: That's just a tab before that field instead of the space that the original seems to have there isn't it?

Comment: What are `edit` and `desired` supposed to be showing us? SOmething about your input? output from some tool?

Comment: @Ed Morton the `gawk` command produces the edit and that seems to have a space after `$4`.  The desired does not have a space but has a tab.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` will rewrite the line with the specified OFS. If you want to preserve the input spacing you can choose a simpler solution with `sed`

```
sed -r 's/\|.*\|/\|/' file
chr1    955543  955763  + AGRN-6|gc=75
chr1    957571  957852  + AGRN-7|gc=61.2
chr1    970621  970740  + AGRN-8|gc=57.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another *curious* `awk` alternative:

```
awk  '{print $1""$2}' FS='pr=[0-9]\\|' file
```

**Results**

```
chr1    955543  955763  + AGRN-6|gc=75
chr1    957571  957852  + AGRN-7|gc=61.2
chr1    970621  970740  + AGRN-8|gc=57.1
```

**Explanation**

The value of `FS` could be any `regex`, so we can use `pr=[0-9]|` as separator and print the fields before and after it.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{n=split($5, a, "|"); print $1,$2,$3,$4" "a[1]"|"a[3]}' OFS="\t" input
```

Comment: Thank you very much everyone :).

Comment: The output of the `sed` command seems to incorporate a space not a tab after `$4` that is causing issues.  I posted the output in the original post under edit.  Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris So what's wrong with the `awk` command in your question? It seems to be adding the tabs where you need them.

Comment: the `awk` seems to add a tab after `5` then a newline and I think that tab after `$5` is causing issues.  Thank you :).